# Wrap divs around another floating div layout

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I've been trying to work around a layout I'm trying to do. I'll show the basic layout I'm trying to do:
[image]

Ok, what I did was having the red block as a `float: left` div and the other section which have the black blocks as a `display: block` div that holds many `display: inline-block`. My problem is that it looks similar to what I want, but as the beautifull drawing show, there's space on the right that could be used on certain resolutions, and I was thinking that maybe I could center everything horizontally, but it's not really as easy as I thought.

Maybe I'm trying with the wrong "tooling", do you think this should be done with something like a `grid`?
I've been trying to search for something that match what I want but I had no luck. Thanks in advance for any help :)

**EDIT**
By design the black divs have a fixed width, and I cannot change that width, this screen should be able to show whatever amount of divs enter, so in this case we have 3 black divs but it could display 2, 4, depending on the screen, but the particular drawing was to illustrate the cases where it can't show 4 and left a huge white space on the right, thus the need to horizontally center the section.

Comment: Have you tried changing the width values for each div? If you have four divs with equal spacing you could use `width: 25%;` so the divs' respond to the browser window size.

Comment: It's not a bad idea but the problem is that those divs have a fixed width by design and I cannot change them, it's not needed that I si okay 4 items but the amount that it can show (in a larger or smaller display this would break) [Added this detail to the question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine posting a question to stackoverflow and resolving all of this making the `block` div that contains the black divs `text-align: center;` and fixing it.

That's what I did and worked like a charm <3

Comment: If this is the answer that solved your problem; @Tomas Di Vito please mark it as the answer so others don't attempt to provide an answer.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days but I will :)